# Baumslag-Solitar Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, geometry

I am working on an exercise which says Hyperbolic groups do not contain any Baumslag-Solitar group $\operatorname{BS}(m,n)$ as subgroup.
(Hint is $\operatorname{BS}(m,n)$ is not virtually cyclic).

My attempt is I am trying to show that $\operatorname{BS}(m,n)$ contains $\mathbb{Z \oplus Z}$ using the fact that $\operatorname{BS}(m,n)$ is not virtually cyclic where $\operatorname{BS}(m,n)$ denotes the Baumslag-Solitar group.

Any hints are appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me suggest taking a closer look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). You may have observed in your time here on math.stackexchange that questions with little other than a statement "I want to show" can quickly attract down votes and close votes. Putting more effort into providing context will greatly improve your questions and can attract good and helpful answers.

Comment: Why are you trying to show something that is not true?

Comment: Why is it not true? And if not, then what should be my attempt for the problem I stated.

Comment: Not all Baumslag-Solitar groups contains $\mathbb{Z}^2$. What is true is that they all contain a subgroup of the form $Q\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ for $Q$ locally cyclic. So prove that, and then prove that no hyperbolic group contains a subgroup of this form. (I am not sure what $\operatorname{BS}(m,n)$ not being virtually cyclic has to do with anything though...)

Comment: @user1729 Does ${\rm BS}(2,3)$ really contain a subgroup with that structure? I agree that the hint does not seem particularly helpful.

Comment: @Derek Yes, in general $\langle tat^{-1}, a^m\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$ (unless the group is $\operatorname{BS}(1, m)$).

Comment: @user1729 Ah yes of course! And in general the result needed to prove the result is that, for elements $g$ of infinite order in hyperbolic groups, $\langle g \rangle$ has finite index in $C_G(g)$. (So now the OP has enough hints!)

Comment: @user1729 $\langle tat^{-1}, a^m\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}^2
$ isn't it actually showing that BS(m,n) contains $\mathbb{Z^2}$ except for BS(1,m)? And is it true only the family BS(1,m) doesn't seem to have $\mathbb{Z^2}$ as subgroups?

Comment: @Riya Your removing of your effort meant that the question was closed. So I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 5):

I'll convert my comments into a sketch proof. I should warn though that this exercise is not easy (the original proof used "biautomaticity", while I'll use a fancy, but standard, theorem). I suspect that there are results in your course notes/book which make the problem easier.

Also, the "hint" given is meaningless. For example, non-abelian free groups are not virtually cyclic, but every hyperbolic group contains a non-abelian free group or is itself virtually cyclic... Possibly the hint meant "centralisers of elements are virtually cyclic", which is in fact the key theorem we'll use.

Firstly, start with the following (standard) result for hyperbolic groups. I've copied the statement from Corollary III.$\Gamma$.3.10 (p462) of Bridson and Haelfliger's book *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature* (although the proof there is more general then we need, as it is for "semihyperbolic" groups). It is equivalent to the fact that centralisers of elements are virtually cyclic (why?).

**Theorem A.** Let $H$ be hyperbolic. If $a\in H$ is an element of infinite order then $\langle a\rangle$ has finite index in its centraliser.

Therefore, all we need to do is find for every Baumslag-Solitar group $\operatorname{BS}(m, n)$ an element $g\in \operatorname{BS}(m, n)$ of infinite order such that $\langle g\rangle$ does not have finite index in $C_{\operatorname{BS}(m, n)}(g)$. Lets break this down into a series of facts which need to be proven.

> *Fact 1.* Every non-trivial element of $\operatorname{BS}(m, n)$ has infinite order.

This follows from the fact that $\operatorname{BS}(m, n)$ is an HNN-extension of a torsion-free group (namely $\mathbb{Z}$).

> *Fact 2.* If $\operatorname{BS}(m, n)=\langle a, t\mid t^{-1}a^mt=a^n\rangle$ with $|m|,|n|>1$ or $|m|=|n|=1$ then $C_{\operatorname{BS}(m, n)}(a^n)$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

If $|m|,|n|>1$ then $\langle a^n, t^{-1}ata\rangle$ is abelian, and so by Fact 1 is either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Use the fact that $\operatorname{BS}(m, n)$ is an HNN-extensions to prove that this subgroup is non-cyclic. The case $|m|=|n|=1$ is similar.

> *Fact 3.* If $\operatorname{BS}(1, n)=\langle a, t\mid t^{-1}at=a^n\rangle$ (so $m=1$) then $C_{\operatorname{BS}(1, n)}(a)$ contains a non-cyclic locally cyclic subgroup.

The hint here is that $\langle t^{p}at^{-p}\mid p\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ is not finitely generated, but is locally cyclic (every finitely generated subgroup is cyclic). The key observation needed to prove this is that $(t^pat^{-p})^n=t^{p-1}at^{-(p-1)}$).

Facts 2 and 3 mean that $\langle a\rangle$ does not have finite index in $C_{\operatorname{BS}(m, n)}(a)$, while $a$ has infinite order by Fact 1. The result then follows as if $\operatorname{BS}(m, n)$ embeds into a hyperbolic group $H$ then $C_{\operatorname{BS}(m, n)}(a)\leq C_{H}(a)$, contradicting Theorem A.

Comment: H=$⟨a^{n},t^{−1}at⟩$ is abelian, and so by Fact 1 is either Z or Z2. Use the fact that BS(m,n) is an HNN-extensions to prove that this subgroup is non-cyclic. I can write $a^{n}=(t^{-1}at)^{m}$ Isn't H is cyclic then l, generated as <$t^{-1}at$>?. Why do you say it's non cyclic. I can't see how to use the fact HNN extension is implying that. Can you please elaborate a bit more on this part? Also, it will be helpful if you can suggest some good reference for HNN extension.

Comment: @Riya Oh, I believe that should be $t^{-1}ata$ rather than $t^{-1}at$. I'll edit it on Monday. A good reference for HNN extensions is the book *Combinatorial group theory* by Lyndon and Schupp.

Comment: Why Fact 2 and 3 imply that <a> does not have finite index in $CBS_{(m,n)}$(a)?

Comment: @Riya You need to prove that $\mathbb{Z}^2$ contains no cyclic subgroups of finite index, and similarly for any torsion-free non-cyclic locally cyclic group. (This really follows from the fact that the only torsion-free virtually cyclic group is $\mathbb{Z}$, which is pretty standard.)

Comment: I get that. Thanks. Why $t^{-1}at$ lies in centraliser(a) when |m|>1,|n|>1? Again, $t^{-p}at^{p}$ lies in centraliser(a)?

Comment: I have manged to show t^{-p}at^{p} is in centraliser but not sure for t^{-1}at is in centraliser when we consider the case |m|,|n|>1.Also, to show $H= <t^{-p}at^{p}>$ is locally cyclic, taking two typical elements from H which element generate the two. I am having difficulty finding it. Can you please mention the element that will serve the purpose?

Comment: @Riya That was a second minor error: For Fact 2 the centraliser was meant to be $C_G(a^n)$, not $C_G(a)$. So $t^{-1}at\in C_G(a^n)$. I've corrected that error and also the $t^{-1}at\leftrightarrow t^{-1}ata$ error.

Comment: For Fact 3, it is enough to prove that $\langle t^{-p}at^p, t^{-q}at^q\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}$ for any $p, q\in\mathbb{Z}$; you don't need "typical" elements. Can you see why this is?

Comment: No, I do not seem to have precise argument without looking at the elements.

Comment: @Riya Well, any finite set of element $S$ is a product of finitely many of the $t^{-p}at^p$, so if you can prove that finitely many of the $t^{-p}at^p$ generate a cyclic group then $S$ is a subset of a cyclic group, and so $\langle S\rangle$ is cyclic, as claimed. So you just need to focus on the generators $t^{-p}at^p$.

Comment: Yes, I know this, infact I just need to prove that $<t^{-p}at^{p},t^{-q}at^{q}>$is cyclic for some p,q $\in \mathbb{Z}$ but I have not been able to see this how to produce one generator for this.

Comment: @Riya I guess you don't actually need to prove its cyclic; just abelian. The result then follows as either the centraliser is locally cyclic or contains $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Why proving abelian implies it is locally cyclic or contains $\mathbb{Z^2}$? Why not cyclic?

Comment: @Riya It's not finitely generated. The point is that $t^{-p}a^nt^p=t^{-(p-1)}at^p$. This gives you that the subgroup is locally cyclic and not cyclic (why?).